# php login script Undefined variable: _session script

Tags: php, authentication

i am trying to have a login script burt i have this error
Undefined variable: _session
see below the pages

//checklogin.php

```
<?php

ob_start();
$host="localhost"; // Host name 
$username="xxxxx"; // Mysql username 
$password="xxxx"; // Mysql password 
$db_name="test"; // Database name 
$tbl_name="members"; // Table name 

// Connect to server and select databse.

mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

// Define $myusername and $mypassword 

$myusername=$_POST['myusername']; 
$mypassword=$_POST['mypassword']; 

// To protect MySQL injection (more detail about MySQL injection) 

$myusername = stripslashes($myusername);
$mypassword = stripslashes($mypassword);
$myusername = mysql_real_escape_string($myusername);
$mypassword = mysql_real_escape_string($mypassword);
$sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE username='$myusername' and password='$mypassword'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);

// Mysql_num_row is counting table row

$count=mysql_num_rows($result);

// If result matched $myusername and $mypassword, table row must be 1 row

if($count==1){

// Register $myusername, $mypassword and redirect to file "login_success.php"

$_session['name']= myusername;
$_session['pass']= mypassword; 
header("location:login_success.php");
}
 else {
echo "Wrong Username or Password";
}
ob_end_flush();
?>
```

//login_success.php

```
// Check if session is not registered, redirect back to main page. 
// Put this code in first line of web page. 
<?php
session_start();
if(!$_session['name']= myusername){
header("location:main_login.php");
}
?>

<html>
<body>
Login Successful
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You need to capitlize it - it's `$_SESSION`

Comment: also `if(!$_session['name']= myusername)` should probably be `if($_session['name'] != myusername)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is `$_SESSION` not `$_session` you also need to add `session_start()` on top of the page

FROM PHP DOC

> Variables in PHP are represented by a dollar sign followed by the name of the variable. The variable name is case-sensitive.

Comment: he has session_start() there.

Comment: @mistrfu: Not in `checklogin.php`

Answer (score 2):

[`$_SESSION`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.session.php) is to be written capitalized. In your code it is all lower case:

```
if(!$_session['name']= myusername){
```

change to (also add the `$` to myusername):

```
if(!$_SESSION['name']= $myusername){
```

Comment: thanks everyone u are great my mistake sorry , but now i have this       Use of undefined constant myusername - assumed 'myusername' in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/test/login_success.php on line 5

Comment: @LefterisLivanos Add the `$` to `myusername` to mark it as the variable you defined before. Alternatively you can make it a constant and define it by using `define()` somewhere.

Comment: i did what u told me and now the code is :

// Check if session is not registered, redirect back to main page. 
// Put this code in first line of web page. 
<?php
session_start();
if(!$_SESSION['name']=$myusername{
header("location:main_login.php");
}
?>

<html>
<body>
Login Successful
</body>
</html>

Comment: but now i have this error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';' in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/test/login_success.php on line 6

Comment: Sorry For the trouble, i think that all my code is a joke,
  can any one give me a link with login script tutorial to read again because i think i messed up, thans in advanced

Comment: @LefterisLivanos I have none at hand. Just [Google](https://www.google.de/search?q=php+tutorial+login) one. There should be plenty of them.